# Failing to establish connection using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to use requests to get the text off a website, but it is not working and I'm not sure why. Here is my code:

```
import requests

print(requests.get("https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p079_keylog.txt").text)
```

which gives me the following error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='projecteuler.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded 
with url: /project/resources/p079_keylog.txt (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnectio
n object at 0x000002701CC15128>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 
11001] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

So it seems a connection cannot be made. The website is valid and works. Is there anything simple I'm doing wrong that may be causing this?

Comment: Didn't work, still getting the error

Answer (score -1):

You have a little error:

```
print(requests.get("https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p079_keylog.txt").text)
```

`.text` is out of url string but anyway I've tried it and I have not found any error. It seems that you have exceeded the number of requests.

Result:

```
319
680
...
```

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. I'm still getting the error.